# Weird ${\rm Spin}_{\mathbb C}(4)$ isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, spin-geometry

In T. Friedrich, "Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry", the author gives the following exercice (p34) :

Prove that the group ${\rm Spin}_{\mathbb C}(4)$ is isomorphic to the following subgroup $H$ of $U(2)\times U(2)$:
$$H = \{(A, B) \in U(2)\times U(2) : \det (A) = \det (B)\}.$$

This surprised me because in all other textbooks we have ${\rm Spin}_{\mathbb C}(4)\simeq SL_2(\mathbb C)\times SL_2(\mathbb C).$

How can it be that $U(2)\subset SL_2(\mathbb C)$ and $SL_2(\mathbb C)\times SL_2(\mathbb C)\subset U(2)\times U(2)$ ? Did I miss something or is that exercice impossible ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing the compact group ${\rm Spin}_{\mathbb C}(4)$ and the non-compact complex group ${\rm Spin}(4,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Oooh right, so the double cover of $SO(4,\mathbb C)$ is $Spin(4,\mathbb C)\simeq SL_2(\mathbb C)\times SL_2(\mathbb C)$ while $Spin_{\mathbb C}(4)$ is the double cover of, I guess, $SO_o(4,\mathbb C)$ the identity's connected component... That would make more sense ^^
Thanks !